# After audio in background is done, it should go back to the first picture

Tags: javascript, html

I created a satire site, for fun and a portfolio. 
But I also have a problem, I am new to JavaScript and it's not easy.

I created something, when I click on on button on my site. It plays random sounds, and it put in a second picture,
which are great but unfortunately, I don't know how to bring back to original picture, after sound is done, plus if you click again on a button, next sound plays over the first sound.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {



    var bild = "bilder/st_2a.png"
    var audio_files = [
      "sounds/beschnitten/bsound1.mp3",
      "sounds/beschnitten/bsound2.mp3",
      "sounds/beschnitten/bsound3.mp3",
      "sounds/beschnitten/bsound4.mp3",
      "sounds/beschnitten/bsound5.mp3"
  ]

  var random_file = audio_files[Math.floor(Math.random() * audio_files.length)];

  var audio = new Audio(random_file);


 var gesamt = audio.play() + bild;
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Blocher der wahre Retter der Schweiz</h1>
    <p>Bitte klicken Sie den Knopf immer wieder an! V 1.0</p>
  <div id="blocherw">
    <img id="blocherbild" src="bilder/st_a.png" width="600" height="620" alt="standsbild_ausgeschnitten">
  <button id="blocherzufall">KLICK!</button>

  </div>
<script>
</script>


</body>
```

friendly regard

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sound_playing = false;
    var bild = "bilder/st_2a.png";
    var erstes_bild = "bilder/st_a.png";
    var audio_files = [
        "sounds/beschnitten/bsound1.mp3",
        "sounds/beschnitten/bsound2.mp3",
        "sounds/beschnitten/bsound3.mp3",
        "sounds/beschnitten/bsound4.mp3",
        "sounds/beschnitten/bsound5.mp3"
    ];
    $("button").click(function() {
        if (sound_playing) return;
        var random_file = audio_files[Math.floor(Math.random() * audio_files.length)];
        var audio = new Audio(random_file);
        document.getElementById("blocherbild").src = bild;
        audio.onended = function() {
            document.getElementById("blocherbild").src = erstes_bild;
            sound_playing = false;
        }
        sound_playing = true;
        audio.play();
    });
});
        </script>
        <h1>Blocher der wahre Retter der Schweiz</h1>
        <p>Bitte klicken Sie den Knopf immer wieder an! V 1.0</p>
        <div id="blocherw">
            <img id="blocherbild" src="bilder/st_a.png" width="600" height="620" alt="standsbild_ausgeschnitten">
            <button id="blocherzufall">KLICK!</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this is the code you need.

What I did was I stored the original picture in a variable. I changed the image. Then I played the sound and waited for it to finish. Then I changed the image back.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I made a variable that detects if the sound is playing or not. Then I just use the function if the sound isn't playing.

Comment: Thanks mate, like your style of coding :) but you know how can I avoid overplaying the sound if I click on a button again while audio is running?

Comment: I changed my answer to what you needed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, if you could just mark the question as answered, it would be great. Thanks!